# Android Textview text can not change after onActivityResult in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I am trying to change the TextView through setText() on onActivityResult in fragment.
But there is no effect.
here is my code

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (requestCode == 111) {
        if (resultCode == mainActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            String result = data.getStringExtra("districtName");
            Log.w(AppConstants.TAG, " onActivityResult Buy " + requestCode
                    + " " + resultCode + " " + result);
            locationTvBuy.setText(result);
        }
        if (resultCode == mainActivity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my full Fragment Class Code  `public class BuyFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

```
private Context context;

private TableRow loacationSelectBuy;
private TextView locationTvBuy;

private MainActivity mainActivity;

public BuyFragment(MainActivity home) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.mainActivity = home;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buy, container,
            false);

    context = mainActivity;

    initUI(rootView);

    return rootView;
}

private void initUI(View view) {
    locationTvBuy = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.locationTvBuy);

    loacationSelectBuy = (TableRow) view
            .findViewById(R.id.loacationSelectBuy);
    loacationSelectBuy.setOnClickListener(this);

    Tools.rangedSeekbar(view, R.id.minValueTk, R.id.maxValueTk,
            R.id.layoutTkSeekBar, 0, 50000000, context);
    Tools.rangedSeekbar(view, R.id.minValueSf, R.id.maxValueSf,
            R.id.layoutSfSeekbar, 0, 20000, context);

}

String result = "Select Location";

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (requestCode == 111) {
        if (resultCode == mainActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            result = data.getStringExtra("districtName");
            Log.w(AppConstants.TAG, " onActivityResult Buy " + requestCode
                    + " " + resultCode + " " + result);
            // locationTvBuy.setText(result);
        }
        if (resultCode == mainActivity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    Log.w(AppConstants.TAG, " Resume "+result);
    locationTvBuy.setText(result);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.loacationSelectBuy:
        Intent districtIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                DistrictActivity.class);
        mainActivity.startActivityForResult(districtIntent, 111);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

}`
here in log i find the result but the result is not set to TextView
need some help

Comment: are there any errors in your Logcat?

Comment: logcat and more information please

Comment: Are you able to see result value in Logs?

Comment: Here is the logcat result 08-03 01:10:00.671: W/PROPERTY_BAZAAR(18425):  onActivityResult Buy 111 -1 Chittagong             i need the Chittagong to set in locationTvBuy.setText(result);

Comment: Are you resetting your `locationTvBuy` in your `onResume()` method? `onActivityResult()` is called before `onResume()`, so if you set `locationTvBuy` in `onResume()` you'll overwrite the value set in `onActivityResult()`

Comment: could you show us your activity code?

Comment: Here i implement onResume() But same problem occured 
 @Override
 public void onResume() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onResume();
  Log.w(AppConstants.TAG, " Resume "+result);
  locationTvBuy.setText(result);
 }
 Log info in here
08-03 01:26:10.146: W/PROPERTY_BAZAAR(22085):  Resume Chittagong
08-03 01:26:10.151: W/PROPERTY_BAZAAR(22085):  Resume Select Location

Comment: @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
    R.id.main_content);
  fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 } This is onActivityResult in main Activity

Comment: @RodrigoHenriques here i edit my post with full fragment class.

Comment: Could you put a breakpoint at onResume and check what value they are setting to your edit text?

Comment: after investigate i find another thing that my onResume() called two time but why? Log info:-  08-03 02:09:48.498: W/PROPERTY_BAZAAR(26389):  Resume Rajshahi
08-03 02:09:48.499: W/PROPERTY_BAZAAR(26389):  Resume Select Location  i need (Rajshahi ) But Finally set (Select Location)

Answer (score 0):

You must retain that value in onActivityResult but set it in TextView in onStart method.

Comment: I also try this but same problem occured